# Python pip: Forcing the progress bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pipe, tty

When downloading Python packages with pip, a progress bar is displayed by default. Using [`--progress-bar`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-progress-bar) I can choose between different styles or turn the progress bar off entirely. If I pipe the output of a pip command, this progress bar is automatically disabled. E.g.

```
python3 -m pip download --no-cache-dir scipy==1.1.0            # Progress bar
python3 -m pip download --no-cache-dir scipy==1.1.0 | tee log  # No progress bar
```

(if you run both commands in turn, remember to remove the downloaded files in between). I'm sure that pip disables the progress bar because it detects that the output is not going to a TTY. I seek a way to ignore this cleverness of pip and force it to write out the progress bar anyway. The naïve guess would be to supply the `--progress-bar` argument, e.g.

```
python3 -m pip download --no-cache-dir --progress-bar=on scipy==1.1.0 | tee log
```

However, the non-TTY disabling of the progress bar overrules this.

Note: A similar story exists for `wget`. Here, the progress bar can be forced using

```
wget --progress=bar:force ...
```

Comment: Progress bars are weird.  Try coding one yourself in python.  Often you need to use a carriage return character (`\r`) without an accompanying line feed character (`\n`) so that you overwrite the existing line with the updated progress bar text.  If this is how pip does it, your pipe'd output will be hundreds of lines long with most of the outputs being different times the progress bar was printed.  I don't know how to force the progress bar but I doubt you'd actually want it forced for piping to something.

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt I've coded several progress bars myself, I know the gist. I do in fact want to force the progress bar. Sure the log file will be messy, but the output on the screen will be intact.

Comment: The only way is to hack the source and send a pull request.

Comment: I've submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8431)